# WTForms form with custom validate method is never valid

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

I want to get the data for a user input date, or the current date if nothing is entered.  I used WTForms to create a form with a date input, and override `validate` to return `True` if the date field has data.  However, the form is always invalid even if I enter a date.  Why isn't this working?

```
class ChooseDate(Form):
    date = DateField(format='%m-%d-%Y')

    def validate(self):
        if self.date.data is None:
            return False
        else:
            return True

@app.route('/index', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    date_option = ChooseDate()
    print(date_option.date.data)  # always None

    if date_option.validate():
        request_date = date_option.date.data
    else:
        request_date = datetime.today().date()

    return render_template_string(template_string, form=date_option, date=request_date)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren't overriding `validate` correctly.  `validate` is what triggers the form to read the data and populate the `data` attributes of the fields.  You're not calling `super`, so this never happens.

```
def validate(self):
    res = super(ChooseDate, self).validate()
    # do other validation, return final res
```

In this case there's no reason to override `validate`, you're just trying to make sure data is entered for that field, so use the built-in `InputRequired` validator.  Using field validators will add error messages to the form as well.

```
from wtforms.validators import InputRequired

date = DateField(validators=[InputRequired()])
```

See the docs for more on [validation](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.x/validators/).

Finally, you need to pass the form data to the form.  If you were using the [Flask-WTF](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) extension's `FlaskForm`, this would be passed automatically.

```
from flask import request

form = ChooseDate(request.form)
```